# Searching mysql database - php

Tags: php, search

I'm trying to mod a search routing, i have two fields, artist & title, when i search for example Foo Fighters  the pretender, i don't get any results, whereas if i search individually i do. Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

```
  $arraySearch = explode(" ", $searchvalue);
  $arrayFields = array(0 => "Artist", 1 => "Title");
  $countSearch = count($arraySearch);
  $a = 0;
  $b = 0;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE (";
  $countFields = count($arrayFields);
  while ($a < $countFields)
  {
    while ($b < $countSearch)
    {
      $query = $query."$arrayFields[$a] LIKE '%$arraySearch[$b]%'";
      $b++;
      if ($b < $countSearch)
      {
        $query = $query." AND ";
      }
    }
    $b = 0;
    $a++;
    if ($a < $countFields)
    {
      $query = $query.") OR (";
    }
  }
  $query = $query.")";
  $query_result = mysql_query($query);
  echo '<h1>Your Search Results</h1>'."\n\n";
  if(mysql_num_rows($query_result) < 1)
  {
    echo '<p>No matches found for "'.$searchvalue.'"</p>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<p>Search Results for "'.$searchvalue.'":</p>'."\n\n";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
    {
      // output

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This search function is very inefficient.  Since you are searching on a wildcard `%blah%`, it has to do a full table scan to find any records.  That is, if you have 1 million records, it has to read all 1 million records in order to find your search results.  On a busy site with a large table, this can kill your performance and database server.

If you are using the MyISAM engine for the table, I would recommend adding a [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index to the artist and title columns and then performing a fulltext search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE
MATCH(`artist`, `title`)
AGAINST('foo fighters the pretender');
```

As written by the OP, here is a query that sorts by match relevance on the search query

```
$search = $db->escape('foo fighters the pretender');

$query = "SELECT *,
          MATCH(Artist, Title) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
          FROM table
          WHERE
            MATCH (Artist, Title)
            AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          ORDER BY relevance DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks man this seems the way forward for me, although i don't really have time to redo things just now, its a mobile site/app, so it will be getting loads of updates and will deffo be implemented in the next major one, currently there is 80,000 records and around 30 users max at any one time i would estimate, do you think my script would suffice for now?

Comment: Run some `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` queries on a typical search to see how many rows its looking at.  While running under normal load, check your `uptime` and see what the load average is.  Looking at disk IOPS is also a good metric.  This [blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/29/identifying-the-load-with-the-help-of-pt-query-digest-and-percona-server/) on profiling by Percona is a good thing to try as well.  If your searches and/or site start to run slow, it could likely be due to this issue.  It largely depends on the hardware and disks your server is running on.

Comment: no need for that, i'll just take your suggestion, your obviously really intelligent and you know more than me in this area ha :P That is just pretty much garbage the script i was using. Fulltext it is.

Comment: You can alter the table to have a fulltext index like this:  `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD FULLTEXT(title, artist);` to add the index.  Then its just a matter of modifying your searches to use `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax.

Comment: i've tried it and i keep getting an error, mysql fetch array, invalid argument, any ideas ?    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(Artist, Title) AGAINST ('foo fighters pretender')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($query);
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $myrow[Title];
}

Comment: AGAINST ('+foo fighters the pretender' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";    reurns a list of the foo fighters songs, im guessing its just grabbing the tracks by the foo fighters and ignoring the title.

Comment: Did you get any futher I was driving home from work.  I set up a test table and the query `SELECT *
FROM songs
WHERE MATCH (
title, artist
)
AGAINST (
'foo fighters pretender'
)`  returns one record where I have `Foo Fighters` in the `artist` column and `The Pretender` in the title column.  You may also try a query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len';`  This tells you the minimum word length a FT search will look at.  It is usually 3 or 4 by default.  So the term `Foo` is likely not being searched.

Comment: no not yet, thought i would take a little break then go back to it with a fresh head, i think the problem is its just not sorting it by relevance.

Comment: it seems ive got it workin, $query = "SELECT * , MATCH(Artist, Title) AGAINST('$searchvalue' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance from table WHERE MATCH (Artist, Title)  AGAINST('$searchvalue' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC"; i dont know how good its going to be, can you offer any improements on it ?

Comment: That looks pretty good.  I profiled it and it as far as the select goes it looks good.  Time it against the old method and see if it gives you the results a good bit faster and `EXPLAIN` it and you can see some of the differences too.  I don't see any changes I'd make

Comment: Thanks for your help man, been testing it all day and it's pretty sweet, i don't even need to compare it the difference is noticeable, i've just spent the last 2 hours on all my other sites changing them to fulltext, i've always been lazy when it comes to search scripts but this delivers excellent results with minimal effort.

Comment: Yeah fulltext search is great, I just wish InnoDB had something like it too.   Glad to hear that you can notice the difference with the new queries.  That should increase the capacity of your site a good bit.  Good luck!  I'll update my answer to show the final query you ended up using that includes the relevance bit.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$query = $query." AND ";
```

to this:

```
$query = $query." OR ";
```

Essentially you are saying `SELECT... WHERE (field1 like 'foo%' AND field1 like 'bar%')`.  You will never find a row where field1 is like both words unless they were the exact same word.  Its like saying `SELECT ... WHERE id=1 AND id=2`, not going to pull any results, where as `SELECT ... WHERE id=1 OR id=2` will pull rows 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

After you close the parentheses of the query, put a var_dump($query) so you will understand what is happening.

eg: The following code outputs:
string(123) "SELECT * FROM WHERE (Artist LIKE '%foo%' AND Artist LIKE '%fighters%') OR (Title LIKE '%foo%' AND Title LIKE '%fighters%')"

```
<?php

$searchvalue = 'foo fighters';

$arraySearch = explode(" ", $searchvalue);
  $arrayFields = array(0 => "Artist", 1 => "Title");
  $countSearch = count($arraySearch);
  $a = 0;
  $b = 0;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE (";
  $countFields = count($arrayFields);
  while ($a < $countFields)
  {
    while ($b < $countSearch)
    {
      $query = $query."$arrayFields[$a] LIKE '%$arraySearch[$b]%'";
      $b++;
      if ($b < $countSearch)
      {
        $query = $query." AND ";
      }
    }
    $b = 0;
    $a++;
    if ($a < $countFields)
    {
      $query = $query.") OR (";
    }
  }
  $query = $query.")";

  var_dump($query);
?>
```